# Can not implicitly convert type string to (my inbuilt dll) Intelliob.HumanResource.Security

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I have this dll(Intelliob.HumanResource.Security) reference added to my web API.

In VB i am doing something like this.

```
Dim mITPLCurrentUser As ITPLCurrentUser = Session("CurrentUser")
Dim mITPLCurrentUserEmployee As ITPLCurrentUserEmployee = 
                                mITPLCurrentUser.ITPLCurrentUserEmployee
Dim mStateId As int = mITPLCurrentUserEmployee.EmployeeWorkStateId
```

But i just cant get this right in c#.

c#

```
string CurrentUser = dbEntities.empmasters.where(c => c.EmployeeId == 
                     EmployeeID).Select(c => c.Code).FirstOrDefault();

ITPLCurrentUser mITPLCurrenUser = CurrentUser; // this lines gives the error

ITPLCurrentUserEmployee mITPLCurrentUserEmployee = 
                                 mITPLCurrenUser.ITPLCurrentUserEmployee;

int mStateId = mITPLCurrenUserEmployee.EmployeeWorkStateId;
```

I am not using session in my API as i read it is not a good practice doing so in web API. I am retrieving current user through linq as a string and then assinging it to ITPLCurrentUser.

I understand that the type is string and mITPLCurrentUser expects type ITPLCurrentUser. But i just can't understand how m i suppose to achieve this? And also how vb ignores all this type of Castings but c# doesn't?

Comment: Is the details available inside `dbEntities.empmasters` is enough to create an instance of `ITPLCurrentUser `.

Comment: You are selecting `c.Code`, which is probably the string.

Comment: VB is liberal with it's implicit conversions and C# is the opposite. If you add (string) before the object, it'll attempt a conversion.

Comment: @sujithkarivelil : No not all the details are available inside DbEntities.Empmasters. plenty of new properties i am getting through this Intelliob.HumanResource.Securtiy

Comment: @Nkosi : I have already mentioned that c.Code is string. That's exactly what my issue is, how do i use this string or any other way round by which i can assign this string value to mITPLCurrentUser which is of type ITPLCurrentUser.